# Intuition behind Laurent's theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

[image]

Taylor series has a pretty nice intuitive explanation. If you know the position, velocity, acceleration and so on of a particle you can predict it's location at any time.

Does a similar intuitive explanation exist for Laurent series and the theorem above (the one that describes the coefficients of the series as a line integral)?

Comment: Even the "intuitive" explanation for the Taylor series rings false to me, because the derivatives of acceleration and higher are not not really needed to determine the position of the particle in the future. Seeking a physical analogy for a piece of analysis is not usually the best way to go.

Comment: @user_of_math Why are they not needed? If the acceleration isn't constant you need higher order derivatives...

Comment: Well, if the acceleration $a(t)$ is given as a function of time, why would you need its derivatives to determine the position? Integrate twice and you are there.

Comment: @user_of_math But the point of taylor series is that your only given the acceleration at one point. You aren't given $a(t)$, your given $a(0)$ for instance. So you can't integrate it. By your logic, why do you need acceleration or velocity? You just need the position function which you can evaluate at any time to find the position.

Comment: That is why it is such a bad analogy. In physics, it is very rare to deal with derivatives of acceleration; you usually get a(t) from a force law F(t). It is quite artificial to have a physical problem with the known acceleration limited to just one point in time as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Taylor series  let you approximate an analytic function on a disk by polynomials.
That's no longer true on an annulus (e.g. $1/z$ can't be approximated by polynomials on an annulus centred at $0$), but it works if you allow an expansion in negative powers as well as positive (thus rational functions
with a pole at the centre of the annulus).

Comment: Can you also give an intuitive explanation of the formula that gives you the coefficients?

Comment: In the case where $C$ is a circle centred at $z_0$, it's really the same thing as the formula for the coefficients of the complex Fourier series of $g(\theta) = f(z_0 + r e^{i\theta})$, $0 \le \theta < 2 \pi$.

Comment: Very helpful basic explanation! Still a little shady on how to use this series.